# VBA DoCmd.TransferText. Add one more field at access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am transferring from text files to access DB table using DoCmd.TransferText. Just that for each record created in my access DB table, apart from the text file lines, i would like to add one more field to each record, but for DoCmd it seems to be a constraint. Is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the text file into a staging table then
run a make table query or Append Table Query into your finished table.  In the query add the needed field(s) via calculation in the Query Design:

Myfield:Null or MyField:IIF(SomeOtherField="M", ...) etc.  Then save the query.

In your VBA (Assuming that "StagingTable is where you import the file and 
AppendStagingTableToWorkTable is your appendquery:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "My Import Spec", "StagingTable", _
    "C:\TextFile.txt", False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "AppendStagingTableToWorkTable"
```